# ASP MVC javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to fitlra by name and as a result, I refresh the table by jquery, but I don't know why it reloads the HTML of the page and duplicates the HTML. I leave my code and photos.

my controller

```
public ActionResult About(prueba1 model)
{
    if (model.Nombre != null)
    {
        Dbcon.Conexion con = new Dbcon.Conexion();

        SqlParameter[] arrParam = new SqlParameter[1];
        arrParam[0] = new SqlParameter("@nombre", model.Nombre);
        arrParam[0].DbType = DbType.String;
        arrParam[0].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        
        return View(con.Tablin2(arrParam).ToList());
    }
    else
    {
        Dbcon.Conexion con = new Dbcon.Conexion();

        return View(con.Tablin().ToList());
    }

}
```

my view and my javascript

```
<div class="row">
    <table id="tablen">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Periodo</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Edad</th>
            </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <th>@item.periodo</th>
                    <th>@item.Nombre</th>
                    <th>@item.edad</th>
                </tr>
            }

        </tbody>

    </table>
</div>
```

```
@section Scripts{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
}
```

```
$(function ()
{
    $("#buscador").click(function ()
    {
      var nombre = $("#nombre").val();

      if (nombre == null || nombre == "") {
        alert("Cuidado");
        return;
    }
      
        // probar que valor  console.log(cuenta);

        var dataToPost = {};
        dataToPost.nombre = nombre;

      $.post("@Url.Action("About","Home")", { model: dataToPost }, function (data) {
      $("#tablen").html(data);
      $("#tablen").show();
    }); 
    });
});
```

Help me, please

Thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XU17k.png)

[the second time no duplica](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNT5Q.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGbc1.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDMBv.png)

Comment: Please be careful in writing your question and do it patiently

Comment: You have included jQuery twice in your page. This is not necessary. Just use one version.

Comment: `I don't know why it reloads the HTML of the page and duplicates the HTML` ...because this code: `$.post("@Url.Action("About","Home")", { model: dataToPost }, function (data) {
      $("#tablen").html(data);` tells the server to return the whole HTML for the "About" view again, but this time put it inside the "tablen" table. So you'll see a page within a page, effectively. I think you should either a) learn about Partial Views so you can just return the HTML needed for the table from a separate action method, or b) learn about JSON to just return the _data_ needed to populate the table.